# How to silence the logger from a specific library

Tags: logback, slf4j

I am using a library in my code which has the following logback.xml

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date - %-5p %t %-25logger{0} %F:%L %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

I have no control over this .xml file because the library author owns this file and I just use her library as a jar file.

Now when I use the library as a jar, I see lots of "INFO" statements in my output. I want to shut the output of the logger just from this library.

I don't want to globally switch off (or raise severity of logs) for my application. I just want to silence the logs from this library.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should report to the library owner.  The whole idea of SLF4J is to let final application decide which logging backend to use.  Library shouldn't contains logback and logback.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem. I am listing my solution here for others.

So the problem is that we have multiple libraries and each has its own logger. we want the output from some and not from others. We can easily simulate this by the example below

```
package com.abhi

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

object Program extends App {
   val f = new Foo()
   val b = new Bar()
   f.sayHello("Test1")
   b.sayHello("Test2")
}
class Foo {
   val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[Foo])
   def sayHello(name: String) : String = {
      logger.debug(s"++++++++++++ came inside Foo sayHello(${name}) +++++++++++++++++++++")
      "Hello " + name
   }
}

class Bar {
   val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[Bar])
   def sayHello(name: String) : String = {
      logger.debug(s"++++++++++++ came inside Bar sayHello(${name}) +++++++++++++++++++++")
      "Hello " + name
   }
}
```

Now let's say we want to keep the output from Foo logger but don't want the output from Bar logger.

We will adjust our logback.xml like

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.abhi.Foo" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <root level="off" />
</configuration>
```

Here we are setting a logger explicitly for foo and setting its level to trace and setting the root to off. All people who don't have specific loggers will go to root and will not be able to log anything.

Comment: This is untenable. The idea is to single out one logger, not to use the bazooka and pick up the pieces

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the location of your logback.xml as a system property, then you can change it.

As the logback document says:

> **Specifying the location of the default configuration file as a system property**
>
> You may specify the location of the default configuration file with a system property named "logback.configurationFile". The value of this property can be a URL, a resource on the class path or a path to a file external to the application.
>
> **java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/path/to/config.xml chapters.configuration.MyApp1**
>
> Note that the file extension must be ".xml" or ".groovy". Other extensions are ignored. Explicitly registering a status listener may help debugging issues locating the configuration file.

---

**UPDATE**

To suppress logs from a specified package, you can define a logger in the logback.xml.

E.g. To suppress logs from "io.netty" package, add **<logger name="io.netty" level="WARN"/>** to your logback.xml.

Comment: How will this help. even the other library will pick up the same configuration file.

Comment: All libraries SHOULD use the same configuration file.

Comment: In fact, other libraries should not contain logback and logback.xml, including slf4j is enough. In your case if you can't let library owner change it, you can use my method to use your own logback.xml.

Comment: I have my own logback.xml in resources folder. but still I see lot of stuff being logged by the libraries I use. These are libraries I got from maven central. I don't know where the library authors are.

Comment: You can define a logger in your logback.xml to suppress logs from a specified package. e.g. use <logger name="io.netty" level="WARN"/> to suppress logs from "io.netty" package.

Comment: could you please update your answer above... because that is what I am looking for.